# Spring MVC ResourceBundleMessageSource XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I would like to mimic the Grails way of resolving i18n messages.

In WEB-INF/i18n/ I have the following directories:

**admin**/messages_EN.properties

**admin**/messages_FR.properties

**website**/messages_EN.properties

**website**/messages_FR.properties

*please ignore the language endings ( EN and FR ) in this example*

in my xml configuration I currently have:

```
<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
  <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/i18n/" />
</bean>
```

What I am looking for here, is a way to tell Spring to look for .properties files under i18n but without explicitly telling it what each subdirectory is. That is **without** a **list** of **basenames** that points to */WEB-INF/i18n/admin/* and */WEB-INF/i18n/website/*

I want the WEB-INF/i18n/ directory to be dynamic, and that bundles ( directories ) can be created without having to remodify the xml configuration file.

**I am not trying to solve this particular example with admin and website sub directories**

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably have to extend `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to introduce some sort of `discover` property that causes the message source to search the `basename` directory, instead of loading files directly.

Comment: @PaulGrime I have implemented something based on your suggestion and edited my question to include the suggested implementation. Something along these lines should work right? Missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
package com.mypackage.core.src;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class UnderDirectoryReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setWorkingDirectory(String directoryPath) {
        File rootDir = new File( servletContext.getRealPath(directoryPath) );
        ArrayList<String> baseNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        iterateScanDirectoryAndAddBaseNames(baseNames, rootDir);
        setBasenames(baseNames.toArray(new String[baseNames.size()]));
    }

    private void iterateScanDirectoryAndAddBaseNames(ArrayList<String> baseNames, File directory) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                iterateScanDirectoryAndAddBaseNames(baseNames, file);
            } else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".properties")) {
                    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/").replaceAll(".properties$", "");
                    filePath = filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf("/WEB-INF/"), filePath.length());
                    baseNames.add(filePath);
                    System.out.println("Added file to baseNames: " + filePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

XML config:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.mypackage.core.src.UnderDirectoryReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
  <property name="workingDirectory" value="/WEB-INF/webspring/i18n" />
  <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3" />
  <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Enjoy!