# How to use a properties file outside of WEB-INF directory?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project (created with maven) and I have spent the whole day trying to find a way to use a properties file outside of the `WEB-INF` directory.

For example I tried to put it in the resources directory but this does not work at all.

If I put the properties file in the `src/main/resources` directory the compilation of the project is putting this file inside the `target/{project name}/WEB-INF/classes` directory so the `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` bean cannot read it from there.

If I put the properties file inside `WEB-INF` directory then the file is copied in the `target/{project name}/WEB-INF` directory and the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` bean can read it.

Is there any way I can use the properties file when I put it outside of the `WEB-INF` directory for example inside the resources directory?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035588/dynamically-load-files-on-classpath-using-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource

Comment: So I see in this link that ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is only working with property files inside WEB-INF.Should I use another spring framework class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `basenames` to `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. From [`#setBasenames`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasenames-java.lang.String...-) documentation:

> Set an array of basenames, each following the basic ResourceBundle convention of not specifying file extension or language codes, but in contrast to ResourceBundleMessageSource referring to a Spring resource location: e.g. "WEB-INF/messages" for "WEB-INF/messages.properties", "WEB-INF/messages_en.properties", etc.
>
> XML properties files are also supported: .g. "WEB-INF/messages" will find and load "WEB-INF/messages.xml", "WEB-INF/messages_en.xml", etc as well.
>
> The associated resource bundles will be checked sequentially when resolving a message code. Note that message definitions in a previous resource bundle will override ones in a later bundle, due to the sequential lookup.

If you are using XML configuration you can use like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basenames="classpath:localization/messages" />
```

In java config will look like this:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // other configurations
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:localization/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Will work with all `properties` files on classpath called `messages*.*` in `localization` directory. In java project they are in `src\main\resources\localization`.

Comment: It is working.The only strange thing remaining is the red marking from intellij idea.If I remove the 'classpath:' part of the string the ide stops complaining about it but the properties file is not used by the project.And in all possible scenarios (even when the property is properly used) if I enter the properties file IntelliJ Idea is complaining about property not used!

Comment: @skiabox I don't know intellij, possibly is a XML validation, no?

Comment: Maybe I should make a post at their forums.Thank you anyway for your answer.