# Spring reload properties without restarting TOMCAT

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, apache-commons, dynamic-properties

I have this Spring MVC application that makes use of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load properties using @Value annotation.
I understand that all properties are loaded at server startup when context is initialized. 
Howevver, is there a way that I can access updated properties without having to restart TOMCAT? (perhaps making use of Apache Commons PropertiesConfiguration)?

Is there a way I can configure Apache Commons PropertiesConfiguration to work with Spring PropertyPlaceholderconfigurer?

Comment: You can try to use ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, details are in this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035588/dynamically-load-files-on-classpath-using-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RefreshScope` annotation above the class which consumes the properties (ie has @Value annotation). Example goes as follows:

```java
@RefreshScope
class PropertiesConsumer {
  ....
  @Value(..)
  private consumerFoo;
  ....
}
```