# How to load property file values dynamically in apache camel + spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, apache-camel

I am a newbie using camel 2.17 with spring. I have a processor which receives an error code from a web service and I configured the error description in the property file like

```
  myproject.errorCode=1001:error1 description, 1002:error2 description, 1003:....
```

Currently I am reading the value  **myproject.errorCode** using property injection and parsing all the errorCode with description which is working fine. But the error code list is very huge and maintaining it in a single property is very difficult. So I want to split the properties like

```
   myproject.errorCode.1001=error1 description
   myproject.errorCode.1002=error2 description
   myproject.errorCode.1003=error3 description
   .....
```

and I want to read the property in my processor class according to the error code received from the web service like

```
  String errorCodeRecieved  = myWebService.getErrorCode();
  String errorString = "myproject.errorCode.";
  String errorDescription = something.getProperty(errorString + errorCodeRecieved);
```

How can I achieve this facility. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a [MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) available in your context,

```
@Bean
MessageSource myMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource r = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    r.setBasenames("/messages/sample");
    r.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return r;
}
```

And then use this in your processor to fetch the appropriate message like:

```
messageSource.getMessage(code, null, null, locale)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick response. Your solution is working fine. But the problem is I need to add the property file in class-path and in production I need to configure my property file outside the class-path. I couldnt find a way to specify the file-path outside my class-path. There is no method to set file name in **ResourceBundleMessageSource** .

Comment: I think you could user ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, perhaps you can find more info on its usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035588/dynamically-load-files-on-classpath-using-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)

Comment: Hi, @Panayiotis Poularakis  Thanks for your replay... working well.. set the base name as my property file path+propertyname... marked as accepted answer...