# Spring Internalization: how to configure dynamic path for resource bundle message Source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resourcebundle

When we define the ResourceBundleMessageSource, we also provide the folder path (because all the files are in same `locale` directory, - xyz.properties, xyz_fr.properties etc etc
it works seamlessly

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("localisation/xyz");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
```

But in my case, the localized properties files are under directories

```
---resources
--------locale
-----------default
----------------xyz.properties
-----------fr
----------------xyz.properties (containing the french translation)
....
..
```

etc etc

How can have this custom path configured instead of a hard coded string path like above..

Comment: `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` will probably help, see  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035588/dynamically-load-files-on-classpath-using-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource`

Comment: With the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` you cannot as that uses a `ResourceBundle` (which is from the JDK ,**not** Spring) which has strict loading rules and which is basically what enforces the pattern. You might have some luck with the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` but that follows more or less the same pattern to determine if a file is for a certain locale or not (the prefix with `_en_GB` etc. So if you really want/must you probably are going to need a custom implementation for this.